# Is there any way to increase the FPS for the webcam output using MQTT?

Tags: python, mqtt, face-recognition, streamlit

I have been trying to display the output of my webcam on the streamlit.

I referred this repository (https://github.com/robmarkcole/mqtt-camera-streamer), which uses MQTT to display the output of the webcam on the streamlit. However, the performance is not high, and there is lot of lag.

The author of this repository suggests using Frigate (https://github.com/blakeblackshear/frigate) to obtain high performance, but Frigate uses docker for the whole process. And I have a particular environment ready for my project and integrating that environment with docker would take a long time, as I don't have much knowledge about docker.

I want to use this process to perform Face recognition and display the output of the face recognition on streamlit. Is there any possible way to increase the FPS using the MQTT streamlit github repository (https://github.com/robmarkcole/mqtt-camera-streamer)?

Please let me know your inputs to resolve this. 
Thank you.